# Dicom UnCompression by Dcm2dcm

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I am getting compressed dicom files from my server and uncompressed using Dcm2Dcm API but the problem is not getting original dicom image. I got image with some dots and circles..so please provide any solution.

This is original compressed image.

[image]

This is after uncompressed image.

[image]

Comment: From the images you have provided it appears that the resolution of the image has changed. Are the number of rows and columns actually changing or is this just an artifact of the way the images are being captured?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with CT image here and they are normally in Hounsfield units (HU). If so, your image data is signed and you need to account for the signed pixel data in your rendering.